# "From is not valid at this position" this is the syntax error I am getting while using Update join in mysql-Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRtP0.png)I want to update the Paid column in Product when payment amount get inserted with respect to the product...

```
create table Product(
PID INT primary key,
Paid int not null default 0 ,
Total int not null
);



create table payment(
paymentid int primary key,
productid int not null,
amount int not null,
foreign key (productid) references product(paid)
);

(I am just using the dummy table to practice update using join)


update product 
set product.paid=(pay.amount+pr.Paid)
from-----> here I am getting error
payment pay 
inner join product  pr on
pay.productid=pr.pid;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: product-->(id,paid,total_amount) values (100,0,500)
payment-->(pid,id,amount) values (1,100,200) ---> after inserting this I want to add payment.amount to the product.paid. 

For doing this I have written a query but I am getting a syntax error at from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    create table product(
PID INT primary key,
Paid int not null default 0 ,
Total int not null
);



create table payment(
paymentid int primary key,
productid int not null,
amount int not null,
foreign key (productid) references product(paid)
);
```

---

```
UPDATE
        product
    INNER JOIN payment ON product.PID = payment.productid
    SET
        product.Paid = (product.Total+payment.amount)
    WHERE
        product.PID = payment.productid
```

I test It now works fine. I hope It will work fine for you. Please let me know. If you still face same issue.Thanks.
For more details.
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/

Comment: I have added a screenshot. This still showing error at FROM

Comment: Hello,I have corrected it and Test it.I hope the updated answer will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Does it mean we can not FROM in update statements?

Comment: I see in the documentation it is not need when we update. Please take a look more details https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/